# How can I get the "Dictate text" action in a Shortcut to wait longer for the user to speak?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app, voice-dictation

In a set of workflows I'm developing, I pause the workflow to wait for the user to do something and wait for the user to speak certain keywords. The step to wait for the user to speak uses the *Dictate text* action. Unfortunately, *Dictate text* does not wait for long before it returns. That wait time is frequently too short, so I ended up creating a routine that uses a loop to keep repeating *Dictate text* until the user says something:

[image]

This mostly works, except that when the loop repeats right around the moment user happens to speak, it does not capture what the user says, and the user has to repeat it.

**Is there a better method?** Can *Dictate text* be controlled to wait longer, or is there another text input method, or some other approach I didn't think of?